# How to control the order of a variable mixed with string and numbers in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data.frame `df`

```
library(tidyverse)
df<-data.frame(x=paste0("S", 1:15), y=letters[1:15], stringsAsFactors=F)%>%
              arrange(x)
     x y
1   S1 a
2  S10 j
3  S11 k
4  S12 l
5  S13 m
6  S14 n
7  S15 o
8   S2 b
9   S3 c
10  S4 d
11  S5 e
12  S6 f
13  S7 g
14  S8 h
15  S9 i
```

How can I arrange the `x` as an output like:

```
     x y
1   S1 a
2   S2 b
3   S3 c
4   S4 d
5   S5 e
6   S6 f
7   S7 g
8   S8 h
9   S9 i
10 S10 j
11 S11 k
12 S12 l
13 S13 m
14 S14 n
15 S15 o
```

Comment: I saw the post but I think they are different questions.

Comment: `df[gtools::mixedorder(df$x),]` seems to work fine. Also, what happens If you have something like `S01`? The accepted `nchar` answer might fail in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible way within `dplyr` -

```
df %>% 
  arrange(nchar(x), x)

     x y
1   S1 a
2   S2 b
3   S3 c
4   S4 d
5   S5 e
6   S6 f
7   S7 g
8   S8 h
9   S9 i
10 S10 j
11 S11 k
12 S12 l
13 S13 m
14 S14 n
15 S15 o
```

Comment: @DavidZ Just make sure there are no white-spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can you the `mixedorder()` function in the `gtools` package to do this pretty easily.

```
library(gtools)

df<-data.frame(x=paste0("S", 1:15 ), y=letters[1:15], stringsAsFactors=F)


# mix it up
set.seed(121)
df <- df[sample(row.names(df), nrow(df)),]

# reorder it
df[mixedorder(df$x),]
```

That goes from this:

```
     x y
6   S6 f
3   S3 c
2   S2 b
15 S15 o
5   S5 e
12 S12 l
9   S9 i
10 S10 j
11 S11 k
8   S8 h
7   S7 g
1   S1 a
14 S14 n
13 S13 m
4   S4 d
```

to this

```
     x y
1   S1 a
2   S2 b
3   S3 c
4   S4 d
5   S5 e
6   S6 f
7   S7 g
8   S8 h
9   S9 i
10 S10 j
11 S11 k
12 S12 l
13 S13 m
14 S14 n
15 S15 o
```

In tidyverse you can do this -

```
df %>% 
  slice(mixedorder(x))
```

Comment: If the rownames already 1:15 and the x ordered as S1, S10, S2. It doesn't work.

Comment: Why not? What do rownames have to do with your sorting? What `mixedorder` does it strips the numbers from the strings and orders those numbers.

Comment: You may try the df I generated (ending with arrange())

Comment: This seems to work `df[gtools::mixedorder(df$x),]`

Comment: @DavidZ you need to use `slice()` with `mixedorder()` and not `arrange()`. So - `df %>% 
  slice(gtools::mixedorder(x))` gives desired result.

Comment: Thanks! That's a great point

Answer (score 0):

Well you could also add a pure numerical sequence column to your data frame and sort by that.  Then, just scope the columns you actually want to see:

```
df<-data.frame(ord=c(1:15), x=paste0("S", 1:15), y=letters[1:15], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df[order(ord), c("x", "y")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not this?

`df[order(nchar(df$x),df$x),]`